# Is there anything special in a matrix when one of its eigenvector is all one?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If we calculate eigenvectors of a matrix $A_{n*n}$, when all of the elements of one of the eigenvectors is equal to 1 ($x = \textbf{1}_{n*1}$), we can say that sum of the elements in each row is equal to the eigenvalue associated to $x$, but is there anything special about $A$?

Comment: Do you think there should be for some reason?

Comment: well, one of the properties is that $A / \lambda$ is a *Stochastic* matrix (if the elements are non-negative), that is a matrix that can be entered into a Markov chain ...

Comment: @AdamHughes I have read in a book that when $A$ is a covariance matrix of a zero mean vector $u$, if one of the eigenvectors of $A$ is equal to $\textbf{1}$, then the KL transform of a new vector $u' = u + \mu$ ($\mu$ is constant) remains unchanged relative to u.